# Como pasar datos de una clase a un Binding en App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

Este es el App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Subclases.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Subclases"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="sTB" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}"/>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource sTB}" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Name="sB">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Border_setters.color_border}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding Border_setters.grosor_border}"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="{Binding Border_setters.radio_border}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource sTB}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" x:Key="sT">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=TextBox_setters.height_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.foreground_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.background_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.width_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.fontsize_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.horizontalA_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.verticalA_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.margin_txt}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.padding_txt}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="prueba" TargetType="TextBox" x:Name="prueba">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding TextBox_setters.width_txt }"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Necesito poder enviarles los datos que necesitan para que puedan aplicar los Setters de forma correcta.
Esta son las clases que contienen los objetos que debo enviarles al Binding de los Setters en App.xaml.

```
class Border_setters
{
    public string color_border = "Black";
    public string grosor_border = "5";
    public string radio_border = "Black";
}

class TextBox_setters
{
    public int height_txt() { return 50; }
    public string foreground_txt() { return "White"; }
    public string background_txt() { return "Red"; }
    public int width_txt() { return 200; }
    public string fontsize_txt() { return "16"; }
    public string horizontalA_txt() { return "Center"; }
    public string verticalA_txt() { return "Center"; }
    public string margin_txt() { return "10"; }
    public string padding_txt() { return "10"; }
}
```

El motivo de yo hacer eso asi es que necesitare cambiar los parametros con un Textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descubri como hacerlo muy facil. Primero debia agregar `local:()` y cambiar los metodos por constructores.

```
<Style x:Key="sTB" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=(local:TextBox_setters.height_txt)}"/>
            </Style>
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Solo puse uno solo por que seria innecesario hacerlo con cada uno de los que estan alli.

```
public static class TextBox_setters
{
    public static string height_txt
    {
        get { return "100"; }
        set { }
    }
}
```